# Background task not working when disconnected from Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have an app that performs a task when it enters the background. When I run the app on my device from Xcode, it works correctly. But if run it from my device while disconnected, it doesn't work.

The issue appears to be time related. If I leave it in the background over ~15 minutes it doesn't work. But when running from Xcode it doesn't matter how long I let it sit in the background.

I've updated the Run scheme to release and also generated an IPA using Archive and tested with that. I checked the device log and nothing appears there.

What might be different when running from Xcode vs the actual device? Does Xcode make background tasks run longer than the actual device? Is there some sort of deep sleep the phone goes to when not connected?

Comment: See [App Programming Guide for iOS: Background Execution](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW1). If you edit your question to tell us exactly what you need background execution for, we can advise you further on ways to achieve that.

Comment: Being attached to the Xcode debugger keeps your app alive, running in the background. When you’re not attached to the debugger, iOS imposes limitations on background execution. If you just need a little time to finish up some task, you can ask the OS for a little time (usually maxed out at 3 minutes). Or, if the app has some legitimate need for background execution (e.g. it’s a navigation app, a music player, a VOIP app, etc.), you can register for continuous background execution. But except for these few special cases, apps can’t just keep running in the background indefinitely.